# Mocking methods that been called in method's signatures

Tags: python, python-2.7, mocking, python-unittest

I'm looking for a way to mock a method that has been called as a result of getting the default value of an argument.

For example, a.py is:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, arg=ToBeMocked())
```

`ToBeMocked()` will be called after calling:

```
from a import A
```

How can `ToBeMocked()` be mocked before calling the import statement?

Comment: Show us the body of `__init__`!

Comment: ToBeMocked  called even before going into the body of the __init__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [unittest.mock.patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) to patch `ToBeMocked` function before importing `A` class from `a` module.

E.g.

`a.py`:

```py
from arg import ToBeMocked


class A():
    def __init__(self, arg=ToBeMocked()):
        self.arg = arg
```

`arg.py`:

```py
def ToBeMocked():
    return 'teresa teng'
```

`test_a.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest import mock


class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('arg.ToBeMocked')
    def test__init__(self, mock_ToBeMocked):
        mock_ToBeMocked.return_value = 'Love Teresa Teng'
        from a import A
        a_instance = A()
        self.assertEqual(a_instance.arg, 'Love Teresa Teng')
        mock_ToBeMocked.assert_called_once()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
Name                                   Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
--------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/59178731/a.py            4      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/59178731/arg.py          2      1    50%   2
src/stackoverflow/59178731/test_a.py      11      0   100%
--------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                     17      1    94%
```